# Where is swagger-play 1.2 module ? Link seems dead

Tags: playframework-1.x, swagger

where can I find swagger-play module for play framework 1.2 ?

The link https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-play return à 404 error. Seeking in project page and google, I find only swagger-module for play framework 2.x, not for play 1.2.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

We removed the public availability of swagger-play for Play 1.X since it is not being maintained and only supports a very old version of Swagger.

If you want to get a copy of the sources, you can send a message to our google group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/swagger-swaggersocket) and I'll send you a copy of it.